# When I use `tap` method later the `map` is not called. i get return from tap

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am doing some correction in the response at `tap` before `map` but i am not getting called the `map` after the `tap` implementation. `map` not consoles me at all.

what is the best way to do some correction in the response before we send to `map` any one help me?

as well let me know exact use of `tap` here.
Here is my code:

```
createTranslationId(translationId: ModelTranslationId) {
        console.log('translationId', translationId);
        return this.http.post<any>(environment.configUrl + `Configuration`, translationId)
            .pipe(
                tap(response => {
                    return Object.assign({}, response, {
                        Response: {
                            'Name': response.Response.Name,
                            'Description': response.Response.Description,
                            'TypeId': response.Response.TypeId,
                            'Type': response.Response.Type,
                            'Id': response.Response.Id,
                            'CreatedBy': response.Response.CreatedBy,
                            'CreatedDate': response.Response.CreatedDate,
                            'UpdatedBy': response.Response.UpdatedBy,
                            'UpdatedDate': response.Response.UpdatedDate
                        }
                    });
                }),
                map(response => {
                    console.log('response3', response);
                    return response;
                }),
                catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: map, transform the response, tap only show the response -tap is using to check or to save in caché mainly-, without change it, It's look like in your code you swapped tap and map

Comment: What result do you need?

Comment: Tap: has no return value, only does something with the data, not altering it; Map: Alter the value and return the alteration. Please swap map and tap and remove the return below the log output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since tap performs operations on a mirrored Observable you can't do modifications on the source, for that you need to work with the map operator

So you can change your function as follow:

```
createTranslationId(translationId: ModelTranslationId) {
  return this.http.post<any>(environment.configUrl + `Configuration`, translationId)
    .pipe(map(response => {
        response = // Your object modifications
    }),
    // Other pipe operators                
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`map()` is your wanted operator to transform response that arrived from the network. See [map operator doc](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map).

`tap()` is simply do something operator based on response. It will not modify existing response, so there is no point returning something inside tap expression. See [tap operator doc](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap)